# Timer in Java swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, sleep

I'm trying to replace `Thread.sleep()` with a java swing timer as I hear that is much better for graphics.

Before, I had something set up like this, but it was interfering with the graphics.

```
while(counter < array.size){
Thread.sleep(array.get(counter).startTime);
//do first task
Thread.sleep(array.get(counter).secondTime);
//do second task
Thread.sleep(array.get(counter).thirdTime);
//do third task
counter++
}
```

Now, I'm trying to replace each `Thread.sleep()` with one of these and then I have the actual events that happen after this, but it does not seem to be waiting at all.

```
int test = array.get(counter).time;
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
}
};
Timer t = new Timer(test, taskPerformer);
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
```

Basically, how do I ensure that the program will wait without giving it any code to execute inside of the timer?  Thank you!

Comment: That's ... not what timers do.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  If you know how, then can you answer how do I have 3 sequential tasks occur in a loop with time in between them one after another?

Comment: You don't want the program to wait.  The idea is that each time a timer ticks it will change the state of the program is some way, which is then painted and the next timer starts...

Comment: you would set a boolean variable to false before sleeping, so each action listeners(if any) or other task managers, would works if and if the boolean variable is true, or other wait for a lock object, then notifyAll after sleeping, what do you mean exactly "will wait without giving it any code to execute inside"?

Comment: How do I tell the timer to check for the value of a boolean?

Comment: @user2511414 How is that different from what the OP is doing now?  The intention (as I read it) would be to find a solution that is more friendly to the requirements of the UI framework

Comment: @MadProgrammer well these are just solutions, and i think you did it well :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer comes down to what it is you want to achieve...

The import things to remember are, Swing is single threaded environment, that is, it is expected that all interactions, changes, modifications, updates and creations to the UI are done so from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Any action that blocks the EDT (such as `sleep`, `wait`, etc) will prevent the EDT from repainting the UI or responding to new events.

One way to achieve this is through the use of `javax.swing.Timer`

This is VERY simple example using 3 timers chained together.  Personally, I would use a single timer configured for a short duration tick and check if the required delay has occurred and then change the state accordingly, but this gets the point across...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleTimer();
    }

    public SimpleTimer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer red;
        private Timer green;
        private Timer yellow;
        private Color color = Color.GREEN;

        private Point spot;

        public TestPane() {
            red = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    color = Color.RED;
                    green.start();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            green = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    color = Color.GREEN;
                    yellow.start();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            yellow = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    color = Color.YELLOW;
                    red.start();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            red.setRepeats(false);
            green.setRepeats(false);
            yellow.setRepeats(false);
            green.start();

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    spot = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int radius = 20;
            int x = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - radius) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);

            if (spot != null) {

                x = spot.x - 5;
                y = spot.y - 5;
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);

            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be use a `SwingWorker`, this allows to do some kind of processing in a background thread (leaving the EDT running), but provides methods by which you can sync results back to the EDT simply.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SimpleTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleTimer();
    }

    public SimpleTimer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Color color = Color.GREEN;

        private Point spot;

        public TestPane() {

            new Switcher().execute();

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    spot = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int radius = 20;
            int x = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - radius) / 2;
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);

            if (spot != null) {

                x = spot.x - 5;
                y = spot.y - 5;
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
                g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2d.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);

            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public class Switcher extends SwingWorker<Void, Color> {

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Color> chunks) {
                color = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                while (true) {

                    publish(Color.GREEN);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    publish(Color.YELLOW);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    publish(Color.RED);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Comment: Hope it helps you in what ever it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: Oh, it definitely will.  It's a subtitle application that will go over any video that has an available SRT (subtitle) file on the web.